# Should the MapReduce job kicked off by HBase shell to count table rows be visible in the JobTracker?

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

The HBase shell help for the count command states:

Count the number of rows in a table. This operation may take a LONG
time (Run '$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar hbase.jar rowcount' to run a
counting mapreduce job).

Is it supposed to run this MapReduce job the normal way, via the JobTracker? Am I supposed to see it in the JobTracker history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The hbase shell count operation is not using MapReduce- it is counting rows by advancing a cursor.

As the documentation that you posted states, run `Run '$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar hbase.jar rowcount` to run a counting mapreduce job

Comment: So, this should be interpreted as a suggestion of the alternative way of counting rows, not the explanation of how the shell count command works, right?